# Program to track edited files?

Tags: version-control

Is there a program for Mac and Windows that I can set to start watching a folder at a certain time in the morning when I start to work and then it tells me which files I have edited later on in the day? This would be really helpful when merging parts of projects that I work on with parts that another person has worked on.

Comment: but i tough that was the main reason for why we use version-control no ?

Comment: [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software) . Download [PAGE](http://git-scm.com/download)

Comment: I'm migrating this to Super User, but you should add more information to this to ensure you get good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These may be of interest:

[Changed files on VISTA](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/view-last-modified-files-on-windows-vista/)

[ChangedFiles](http://www.file.net/freeware/last-changed-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the Mac you can use the `find` command to give you a list of all files that have been modified within the past N seconds. There are [versions of this program that run on windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm), too.

Your other choice is to write your own command. Most modern languages give you access to the filesystem, and give you access to file information such as the last modified time. You should be able to write one in less time than it took to write this question and wait for an answer.